# Meta and Metafor R Package -

Tags: r, metafor

I am currently conducting a metaanlysis in R using the package "metafor". Doing my research I came across a different package for metaanalyses in R, namely "meta". I like the forest plot created by the latter package better (designwise) but unfortunatley some of the data is not the same as in the plot I created with metafor.

Specifically, the data is different only for I^2 and the pooled estimate.

```
meta_1 <- rma(yi=yi, vi=vi, measure="SMD", method="ML", slab=Citation, data=dat)
forest(meta_1)

meta_2 <- metagen(yi,vi^.5,data = dat,studlab = paste(Citation), comb.fixed = FALSE, 
                 comb.random = TRUE, hakn = TRUE, method.tau = "ML", sm = "SMD")
forest(meta_2)
```

Does anyone know why those differences emerge?

Comment: in one of your calls above you square root vi but not in the other. is this just a difference in how the call needs to be made? are all the statistical assumptions the same in both calls?

Comment: This is because the rma function asks for the sampling variance, while the metagen function asks for the standard error as the second argument.

Comment: ok thank you. you are specifying more options in the meta_2 call and you change some of those additional parameters to see if they change the results at all?

Comment: oh thank you! If I leave the "hakn = TRUE" part out, at least the value for the estimate is correct! However, the value for I^2 (and the prediction intervall) did not change.

Comment: good, I think it has to do with the other parameters, if you share your data I might be able to run the code and see where it is coming from

Comment: That would be very helpful! I paste the first effect sizes and their variance of my first studies here.

Comment: `
study<- c(1:10)
yi<- c( -0.48965031,0.64970214, 0.11201680,0.07945655,-0.70874645 
      -0.54922759,0.66768916 , -0.45523574 )
vi <- c(0.10299697,0.14036855,0.05137812, 0.03255550, 0.34913525, 
       0.34971466, 0.07539957, 0.08428983)
dat <- cbind(study, yi, vi)

meta_1 <- rma(yi=yi, vi=vi, measure="SMD", method="REML", slab=paste(study), data=dat)
forest(meta_1)

meta_2 <- metagen(yi,vi^.5,data = dat, comb.fixed = FALSE, studlab = paste(study),
                  comb.random = TRUE, method.tau = "REML", sm = "SMD")
forest(meta_2)
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to get the prediction interval to match across functions but not the I^2 values (even though the difference is off by only 2%). There might be some statistical correction one package is doing compared to the other or it has to do with the RE/FE type of modeling approach.

Anyway I hope this code helps point you in the right direction. To get the CIs to match you also have to use the parameter `method.tau.ci` in `metagen()`.

```
library(meta)
library(metafor)
study<- c(1:10) 
yi<- c( -0.48965031,0.64970214, 0.11201680,0.07945655,-0.70874645 -0.54922759,0.66768916 , -0.45523574 ) 
vi <- c(0.10299697,0.14036855,0.05137812, 0.03255550, 0.34913525, 0.34971466, 0.07539957, 0.08428983) 
dat <- cbind(study, yi, vi) 
dat <- as.data.frame(dat)

meta_1 <- rma(yi=dat$yi, vi=dat$vi, measure="SMD", method="REML", slab=paste(study), data=dat) 
forest(meta_1) 

meta_2 <- meta::metagen(TE =dat$yi,seTE = dat$vi^.5, method.tau = 'REML',
                        method.tau.ci = 'BJ', comb.random = TRUE, comb.fixed = TRUE,
                        sm = 'SMD') 

forest(meta_2)
```

Comment: See: http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/faq#how_are_i_2_and_h_2_computed_i

Comment: @Mike, this is extremly helpful. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @Anna you are welcome! I would also check out wolfgang 's comment for the metafor package.